# check if user likes facebook page no longer working?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have used this method before to check if a user likes a particular facebook page but it doesn't seem to be working now.

I can't find any deprecation notice for the function:

> $checklike =
>   "https://graph.facebook.com/".$user_id."/likes/".$page_id."&access_token=".$access_token;

Any ideas why this won't work?

Comment: It works. Are you sure you're getting user_likes permission beforehand?

Comment: it used to work without the user permission - I guess I need user permissions now?